# how to set range for timestamp in elasticsearch query from text input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elasticsearch, bootstrap-4

i am writing Elasticsearch queries for my project and got struck in time and date range i know i need to include range queries and need to set (lesser than or equal to) and (greater than or equal to) but only problem is that (lesser than or equal to) and (greater than or equal to )should not be static it should be dynamic and should come from text input from Daterangepicker.js and that should be set as upper range and lower range and  and after that query should be executed can anyone help me!!!!

Comment: Maybe you should show a bit of your code and how you currently build your query.

Comment: {
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
    "bool": {
     "must": [{
      "match": {
       "type": "cisco_apic_fault"
      }
     }]
    }
   },
   "aggs": {
    "unique_name": {
     "terms": {
      "field": "domain.keyword"
     },
     "aggs": {
      "unique_count": {
       "cardinality": {
        "field": "dn.keyword"
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }

Comment: the above is my code now i need to include range in it for @timestamp

Comment: Can you update your question with the JS code that you're using to create this query?